# get child node of unknown parent from json format in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodes, parent-child, extract

my function receive a json like this

```
{
    IdontKnowWhatsHere1: [ 
        "item1", 
        "item2", 
        "item3"
    ]
}
```

What I want is to get array values not knowing what their label or parent is,
and better to extract the parent also.

Thanks

Comment: hi @Roman i understand the problem and solution there, the very root is identified so they could easily get the child, but the very root here is unknown

Comment: I do challenge the decision of marking the OP's question as duplicate of the linked SO source. The OP's Q directly points to `Object.entries` or any other solution that generates the same result. And btw, in 2017, having ES5 `Array` methods at hand, a `for` loop based solution is not anymore an appropriate approach.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys of the object, and take the 1st key (index 0). Assign the key to the values, to get the array:

```js
var data = {IdontKnowWhatsHere1: [ "item1", "item2", "item3"]};

var key = Object.keys(data)[0];
var values = data[key];

console.log(key);
console.log(values);
```

If [Object#entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Object#values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) are supported by your browser or you use babel, you can get the keys and values or just the values directly:

```js
const data = {IdontKnowWhatsHere1: [ "item1", "item2", "item3"]};

const [key, entryValues] = Object.entries(data)[0];

const values = Object.values(data)[0];

console.log(key, entryValues);

console.log(values);
```

Comment: It's also possible to use `Object.entries(data)` which will return an array: `[[key, val], [key, val]] ...`

Comment: This is all assuming that OP will always expect the object to have only 1 property (natural assumption, given his example). If he wanted to extract in case of more than one property, there are other solutions.

Comment: @TKoL - indeed. Then iterate with Array#map instead of using `[0]`, and get an array of the results.

Comment: @OriDrori ... the OP's description is not quite clear but to me it looks like the OP wants to get a new list structure that contains both information the key and its related values, thus in case of having `Object.entries` at hand this will be the tool the OP is looking for. Otherwise the OP might be in need for an combined `Object.keys` / `Array.reduce|map` based approach.

Comment: @OriDrori both are working, but the second example using entries is best when you add [0] to get the parent value and [1] to get the child, Thanks a lot you save me :)

Comment: @AljohnYamaro - if you use Object#entries, you can destructure the results to key and values like I did in the example.

Comment: ... for just rounding it up ...

`var data = { IdontKnowWhatsHereA: ["itemA1", "itemA2", "itemA3"], IdontKnowWhatsHereB: ["itemB1", "itemB2", "itemB3"], IdontKnowWhatsHereC: ["itemC1", "itemC2", "itemC3"] };`

`var dataEntryList = /* ES6 */Object.entries(data);`
`console.log('dataEntryList : ', dataEntryList);`

`dataEntryList = /* ES5 */Object.keys(data).map(function (key) { return [key, this[key]]; }, data);`
`console.log('dataEntryList : ', dataEntryList);`